# how to reduce time for mapping java beans using mapStruct

Tags: java

I am using mapStruct library(library will automatically create a implementation during compile time) to automatically map between two Java Beans. i have observed that it is taking around 5-6 seconds. is there way to reduce the time to map. help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is taking 5-6 seconds, how did you measure it, what exactly is bein mapped?

Comment: to map the required field and give the respone

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml or the part of it that fails preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>